# Android Wi-Fi connection

Tags: android-wifi

I want to connect via Android to a router. The router uses Telnet protocol. I know the IP and port. 
How can I connect to the router via Wi-Fi and send a byte message to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to connect to Wi-Fi via an android device, go to the Settings menu->Wireless & Networks -> Wi-Fi -> Wi-Fi settings -> Add a Wi-Fi connection.